# Easier way to return first two indices of a nested array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there an easier way to return the first two indices of an array other than creating a for-loop? Possibly with lodash?

```js
    
const animals = [['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'], ['lion','zebra','tiger']];

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++){ 
   console.log(animals[i].slice(0,2));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array to one with the right slices:

```js
const animals = [['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'], ['lion','zebra','tiger']];

console.log(animals.map(a => a.slice(0, 2)));
```

Comment: doesn't the map function use a loop internally ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: Doesn't that defies what the OP have asked ? or he just want to avoid using a for loop in JS land.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I interpreted "other than creating a for-loop" as not writing a for loop explicitly.

Comment: This should be the correct answer! using map + slice is fast and is vanilla js and it is not cumbersome so I don't know why use anything else.@ZohirSalak There is no way to do it without an implicit or explicit loop. Implicit loops(like map) are generally faster then explicit ones.

Answer (score 1):

lodash introduces interesting method [`invokeMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#invokeMap) that allows code be the shortest:

```
console.log(_.invokeMap(sourceArray, 'slice', 0, 2))
```

But maybe using classic `.map()` is better for readability(because of being well-known) as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Without lodash, you could just map...

```js
const animals = [['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'], ['lion','zebra','tiger']];

const first2 = animals.map(a => a.slice(0, 2))

console.log(first2)
```